# Get dictionary key with one of its values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Having a python dict

`mydict= {'1': ['1', '2'], '1': ['2', '4'], '1': ['5', '6']`

Knowing the unique value `1`, i want to return the corresponding key. In this case `'1'`.

Using `list(element_nodes.keys())[list(element_nodes.values()).index(1)]` returns the Error message `ValueError: '1' is not in list`

Ideally i want to return the coressponding second value for this key. In this case `[1, 2]`

Comment: Use `inverted_dict = {k: v for v, l in mydict.items() for k in l}`, then `inverted_dict['1']`. Note that your dictionary has duplicated keys, so you'll lose information.

Comment: why do you expect `1` to be in the list of values? There are no `int` objects in the values, only `list` objets

Comment: anyway, I thinky ou just want: `[k for k,v in mydict.items() if "1" in v]`